# Get specific item from Wikidata with Sparql

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I want to get the data of a specific wikidata item (e.g. Q1651322) with Sparql and then extract the image URL.

I tried this:

```
SELECT ?pic
WHERE
{
  ?item wdt:P18 ?pic .
  FILTER(?item = 'Q1651322')
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "de" }
}
LIMIT 1
```

and also this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?item WHERE {
  ?item ps:P1629 wd:Q1651322.
}
```

But these queries don't find records. How can I filter for a specific item by its ID?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ?pic
WHERE
{
  ?item wdt:P18 ?pic .
  FILTER(?item = wd:Q1651322)
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "de" }
}
LIMIT 1
```

This query finds the record. It is necessary to prefix the item ID with `wd:`.